# jQuery Select variable from outside function

Tags: jquery

Within my dialog function, I need to set I to be the 'id' of the class that is clicked (e.g when clicking on the first '+ Talk' it should set I = 100006. With my current script it will set I to be 'reqtalkdialog'.

How can I get it to pick up the id of the  instead?

Note: the current script used to pick up the correct id, before I put it within the dialog script. Also, as you can see, I can't set it as a global variable because it needs to be changed depending on what is clicked.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MCam435/NYWg2/8/

HTML:

```
<div id="reqtalkdialog" title="Confirmation Required">
  Would you like to request contact?
</div>

<div id="reqtalk100006" style="display:block"><a href="#" class="reqtalk" id="100006">
<span class="reqtalk_b"> + Talk </span></a> - 100006</div>

<div id="reqtalk100001" style="display:block"><a href="#" class="reqtalk" id="100001">
<span class="reqtalk_b"> + Talk </span></a> - 100001</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#reqtalkdialog").dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   modal: true,
   buttons : {
        "Yes" : function() {
            var element = $(this);
            var I = element.attr("id");
            var info = 'id=' + I;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "resource/talkrequest.php",
                data: info,
                success: function(){}
            });

            $("#reqtalk"+I).hide();
            $("#talking"+I).show();
            //return false;

            $(this).dialog("close");           
            },

        "Cancel" : function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    });

$(".reqtalk").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#reqtalkdialog").dialog("open");
});
```

Comment: you can do sometihng like this, but you'll need to instantiate the dialogs like you are on the one you're already using.  $('#'+$(this).parent().prop('id')).dialog("open");

Comment: You shouldn't use only numbers in id attribute... Use `data-id="100006"` and `$(this).data('id')` to get id instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare it outside the listeners and modify the click one like this:

```
$(".reqtalk").on("click", function(e) {
    I = $(this).attr('id');
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#reqtalkdialog").dialog("open");
});
```

Also remove the variable assigning inside the dialog function:
http://jsfiddle.net/NYWg2/9/

(click the Yes button to see the "I" alerted)

Comment: That's fantastic thank you. I thought it was a simple case of changing where it was declared, but couldn't get my head around it.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but I'm glad I could help ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You can use dialog option:

```
var element = $(this);
var I = element.dialog('option', 'currentId');
```

and in event:

```
$(".reqtalk").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#reqtalkdialog").dialog('option', 'currentId', $(this).attr('id')).dialog("open");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

i updated your jsfiddle and below is what i got working, might not be the best way but it works.

HTML

```
<div id="reqtalkdialog" title="Confirmation Required">
  Would you like to request contact?
</div>

<div id="reqtalk100006" style="display:block"><a href="#" class="reqtalk" id="100006"><span class="reqtalk_b"> + Talk </span></a> - 100006</div>

<div id="reqtalk100001" style="display:block"><a href="#" class="reqtalk" id="100001"><span class="reqtalk_b"> + Talk </span></a> - 100001</div>
<input type="hidden" id="clickedNumber" value=""/>
```

JS

```
$("#reqtalkdialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Yes": function() {
            var numberToHide = $('#clickedNumber').val()
            //alert($('#clickedNumber').val());
            var element = $(this);
            var I = element.attr("id");
            var info = 'id=' + I;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "resource/talkrequest.php",
                data: info,
                success: function() {}
            });
            $("#reqtalk" + numberToHide).hide();
            $("#talking" + numberToHide).show();
            //return false;
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Cancel": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
$(".reqtalk").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#reqtalkdialog").dialog("open");
    $('#clickedNumber').val(this.id);
});
```